# Does simplex assumption make Exponentiated Gradient Method applicable only to a specific optimization problem?

Tags: convex-optimization, simplex

According to page 1 of this lecture [here](https://ttic.uchicago.edu/~tewari/lectures/lecture4.pdf), and page 12 of [here](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nickhar/F18-531/Notes20.pdf), I see that there is always an assumption of a simplex feasible region when using Exponentiated Gradient (EG) Method to solve convex optimization problem. It makes me think that EG is only applicable to the optimization problems which constraints are in the format of $\textbf{1}^T\textbf{x} \leq b$. Does someone have any idea of using EG for a more general case, i.e. a convex objective function with $\textbf{A}\textbf{x} \leq \textbf{B}$ constraints?

In fact, it seems to me that such the assumption is only to initiate the first iterate so that $\textbf{x}_1 = (1/n, 1/n, ..., 1/n)$, where $n$ is the dimension of the variable $\textbf{x}$, is always at the "center". But it's just my guess (which is rarely correct).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually two different questions.

To answer your first question, the algorithm itself only produces iterates in the simplex. In that case, center of the simplex is good initial guess IMO.

Probably, the algorithm can be generalized so that it can be applied on any decision space. But it would heavily depend on properties of the matrix $A$. It is non-trivial and unfortunately, I do not have a reference for it.

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my post to make it become only one question. Can you elaborate the statement "the algorithm itself only produces iterates in the simplex"? Does that mean the assumption of simplex is a must? If so, it would be opposite with your second point, IMHO. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: In the first link you sent, check the line below Eqn (1) where they define $Z_t$ and the comment about it. So, if you use the algorithm as is, it is going to produce results in the decision space $D$ they define in the lecture notes.

About my second point, depending on the properties of $A$, it may be possible to find a mapping between two decision spaces. As such, you can generalize the algorithm. But it is definitely not trivial and probably would be a research topic by itself, if it is not one already.